# How to Check if a Specific Radio Button has been Checked

Tags: php

I'm struggling to find a solution to this frustrating problem. I'm trying to make a simple program that checks how long you want your cookie to last. It works fine if I use different names for the radio buttons. But the obvious problem with that is that the user can select more than 1 option. How do I use the same name and still check if a specific one has been selected? (Code below).

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['secs']) && $_POST['secs'] == '5secs'){
    $UN = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    setcookie('username',$UN,time()+5);
    header('Location: http://localhost/Learning/LearningMore/testing.php');
}else if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['secs']) && $_POST['secs'] == '10secs'){
    $UN = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    setcookie('username',$UN,time()+10);
    header('Location: http://localhost/Learning/LearningMore/testing.php');
}else{
    echo 'Please fill out the whole form.';
}

}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </br>
    5 Seconds: <input type="radio" name="secs" id="5secs"/> 10 Seconds: <input type="radio" name="secs" id="10secs"/>
    </br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the current PHP code to work, you need to set the `value` which you are looking for

```
if(... $_POST['secs'] == '5secs'){
// expects value "5secs"
} else if (... $_POST['secs'] == '10secs'){
// expects value "10secs"
```

You can do it like you always set `value`s:

```
5 Seconds: <input type="radio" name="secs" id="5secs" value="5secs"/>
10 Seconds: <input type="radio" name="secs" id="10secs" value="10secs"/>
```

---

By the way you can shorten your conditions a bit there. `empty()` also checks if a variable is set, so `isset()` is redundant. Also both `secs` cases need `$_POST['secs']` to be set and non empty, so why not combine the if? Then only one comparison is left and you can use a nice `switch()`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['secs'])) {
        switch ($_POST['secs']) {
            case "5secs":
                //...
                break;
            case "10secs":
                //...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Please fill out the whole form.';
}
```

This way you can easily modify your code in the future - eg when you want to make another choice possible. Just add another case and you're good - no additional if checks to forget etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm :) Appreciate the help.